# How to identify spammy domains giving backlinks to my site (to submit in disavow links in WMT)

Tags: google-search-console, backlinks, disavow-links

Google is out with much awaited feature. But out of 100's of domains giving backlink to my site I want to simply find the spammy ones and disavow domain-wise using "domain:" feature.

I'm looking for a tool wherein I'll feed list of domains and then it should tell me a domain's spammy-ness in a scale.

Currently I'm trying Netpeak Checker.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are some additional answers on this duplicate question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54038/how-do-you-find-all-the-links-to-disavow-for-a-google-reconsideration-request?noredirect=1

Answer (score 3):

Unless you've actually received an explicit warning from Google, via Webmaster Tools, (note there are [two flavours of warning](https://plus.google.com/+MattCutts/posts/gik49G9c5LU), differing in severity) stating that action is being taken on your site because of its backlink profile, I wouldn't disavow any links at all.

If you've engaged in link-building activities which you believe may leave you exposed to penalties, you should already have an idea which domains the potentially troublesome links will originate from.

Given the emphasis that Google have put on not using the disavow links tool without good cause, I'd think carefully before relying on any automated process to tell you which links to trash.

Comment: +1 This is the same advice that Google give in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nJgJC8MOfc&feature=g-u-u). Don't worry about disavowing links unless you've been participating in link schemes. (And if you have been buying backlinks, you should already know which domains to disavow.)

Comment: I followed such advice and it has resulted in a algorithmic penalty that is crippling to business. My site has not engaged in such acitivites however, as a retail site, we are linked in lists by bloggers etc, which is considered unnatural now. Do not wait for Google to come to you, go to them.

Answer (score 0):

[SEO Tools for excel](http://nielsbosma.se/projects/seotools/) is a good tool that you can use to find out this information. You can choose how you want to define spammy links but it alloys you to analyse the data by several key metrics such as page rank.

Hopefully this will help you, it is a very useful tool.